# File '/Path/hello.js' is a JavaScript file. Did you mean to enable the 'allowJs' option

Tags: typescript

I created a new directory in which I created 2 files

hello.ts

```
function sayHello(name: String) : String {
  return "Hello " + name;
}
console.log(sayHello("Foo"))
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "out",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", 
    "**/*.spec.ts", 
    "out/**"
  ],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "files": [
    "hello.js"
  ]
}
```

Now when I run `tsc` in my directory. it gives me an error

```
error TS6504: File '/Users/Foo/code/typescript/hello.js' is a 
JavaScript file. Did you mean to enable the 'allowJs' option?
```

Why? I told the compiler to put the output into the "out" directory and ignore anything js files in the out directory (not try to compile them after generating them). Then why is it throwing this error at me?

Comment: Don't you want `hello.js` to be `hello.ts`?

Comment: That js file is the output of the compilation. I just want to run that js file with node. So once the compiler has created that file for me its job is done. why is it throwing an error for the file it created for me.

Comment: You also specify `"files": ["hello.js"]` in your `tsconfig.json`, that should be `hello.ts`. The error message doesn't check whether the file exists.

Comment: yes. that was it. thanks!

Comment: I encountered this error when my package.json was set to `"scripts": { "start": "tsc src/hello.ts node src/hello.js"}` and I fixed it by using `&&` like so: `"scripts": { "start": "tsc src/hello.ts && node src/hello.js"}`

Answer (score 1):

`files` is a list of files to include ([TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files)). It doesn't matter if the file doesn't exist - TypeScript sees that you want to compile it; but wait! That's not a TypeScript file. In this case, you don't even need `files`, because you have included `hello.ts` using a pattern in `include`. However, if you wanted to include a file that matched one of the the patterns in `exclude`, you should use `files`. If you want to keep `files`, just change `hello.js` to `hello.ts`, because that is the name of the file you want to compile:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "out",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", 
    "**/*.spec.ts", 
    "out/**"
  ],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "files": [
    "hello.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In tsconfig.json replace "files":["hello.js"] to "files":["hello.ts"].your tsconfig.json should look like:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "out",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", 
    "**/*.spec.ts", 
    "out/**"
  ],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "files": [
    "hello.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

change allowJs to true and restart your ide